# Correct format for number (CoreData)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In CoreData I set type:

```
Integer 16
```

and inserted int like this:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]
```

and problem is when I get result from CoreData result is not 9, result is: 114726928

Does andbody know's why?

Comment: it seems you think the pointer of the `NSNumber` is the value but it is not.

Comment: try this: `[NSNumber numberWithShort: 9]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
NSInteger number = 9;
NSNumber *numberObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:number];
NSInteger numberFromNSNumber = [numberObject integerValue]; // it will contains the 9
```

it should be fine.

Comment: I get error: Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: @CroiOS, I'm not seeing your code but my code has no implicit conversion.